# Missing output after compile

Tags: python

I write some code for my friend using Python.
I dont know why there is missing output and number.
On PhyCharm there is no error...

Code

```
global x, y, z
x=ord("x")
y=ord("y")
z=ord("z")
v=ord('v')
global w, e, c
c=0

def wynik():
        y = (5/2) * x
        wr = x * y * z
        er = solve(diff(wr), x)
        cx = solve(diff(wr), x=er)
        ez = solve(diff(wr), z=cx)

print x, y, z
```

what is wrong?

//edit
work now.

Comment: That code, as pasted, will not compile. Please make sure the indentation exactly matches your actual code.

Comment: Briefly: you never call the function you define.

Comment: I don't think you are using `global` correctly

Comment: Then how its should be?